# Execute result of Select Statement which in turn are select queries

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table which has 10 Select queries. I want to get 3 random queries from that table and execute all those 3 queries to get their result. I tried using EXEC but it did not work. I dont want to use cursor, as I want to execute the result of the 3 queries in one batch. The queries that I used are

```
DECLARE @SqlStmt nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SqlStmt = 'SELECT TOP (3) SQLQuery FROM [dbo].[Load_Test_Queries] ORDER BY NEWID()'

EXEC (@SqlStmt)
```

The result that I get is

```
SQLQuery

--------------------------------

SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM [dbo].[vw_UI_3PP] WHERE ID IN (80079217,80079218,80079219,80079220,80079222,80079229,80079274,80080221,80080223,80080818,80080852,80080918,80080969,80081051,80081354,80081587,80081617,80081716) OR Range > '70-80%'

SELECT TOP 2500 * FROM [dbo].[vw_UI_3PP] Where Code BETWEEN 1010 AND 1300

SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [dbo].[vw_UI_3PP]
```

What I need is the result of all these 3 statements in one batch. Imagine copying this result and executing in another session in one go.

Comment: Tag the correct DB please

Comment: Sorry @shrek..did not understand your comment

Comment: Many SQL-related questions have different solutions in different RDBMSes. From the syntax of your code snippets I assume you're asking about MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the bit you were missing was how to get the results from the `SELECT TOP 3` query as a single `nvarchar` string, so that you could `EXEC` it:

```
drop table #tmp;
select * into #tmp from (
  select 'select 1' as SQLQuery union all
  select 'select 2' union all
  select 'select 3'
)x;

DECLARE @SqlStmt nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @SqlStmt = coalesce(@SqlStmt, '') + SQLQuery from (
   SELECT TOP (3) SQLQuery FROM #tmp) x
--print @SqlStmt
EXEC (@SqlStmt)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nickolay..I tweaked it as per my requirement and it worked. :)